# Django forms validating boolean values and numbers as string

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a form as shown below,

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    tagline = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    privacy = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=2000)
    home_id = forms.CharField(max_length=32, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'tagline', 'privacy', 'description']
```

and when I pass any field as a boolean or numerical value (say, name=True) , the form validates it form.is_valid returns True while if I skip one field (say name=None), the form says the form is invalid. The form works, but not for a boolean value for any field.

Form also validates correctly for floats, lists and dicts. What am I doing wrong? The same happens for a `form.Form` without mentioning a model.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, none of the fields are boolean. Are you saying if the user enters True in the name field it validates? Are you programically filling the form or using the form fields in a template?

Comment: @kujosHeist Yeah, I am validating data using django rest framework